# Node JS Serial Bootloader

Tags: node.js, bootloader

I am creating a bootloader that reads data from a text file, sends each line to the device, and waits for confirmation that the line has been written to the device's firmware before proceeding to the next line.

So I am now using the async modules, which allow me to wait for a command to be executed before moving forward by calling the cb() callback, however I need to only move forward after data is received and validated by the SerialPort.onData() callback.

Problem is, I cannot figure out how to include the data returned by the callback into the async loop, as the callback should only be initiated once for each port, and I therefore cannot simply include it in the async eachSeries loop.

Any suggestions on how I can feed the data received back from the onData callback so that it can be validated against the data sent before proceeding to the next line ??

```
function cl(dat){return console.log(dat);}

port.open(function(err){            
    fs.readFile('CS-BT_J.hex', function(err, f){
        var hex = f.toString().split('\n');     
        var async  = require("async");   
        async.eachSeries(hex, function(item,cb){ 
            outStr = String.fromCharCode(1) + item + String.fromCharCode(13);
            port.write(outStr, function(err,res) {});               
            cb();
        },function(err){});
        });

    port.on("data", function (data) { 
        cl(data);
        //if(data == addr) cb();
    });         

});
```

Comment: A little more detail on what exactly the problem is would be helpful:  where/what is the error exactly, what are you expecting to see, what are you seeing, what is in CS-BT_J.hex?  Trying to duplicate error but I'm assuming it's with reading the file line by line and getting var item to be same as one line in file.  If that is correct, then what you have seems to be working for me

Comment: It sounds like your code is going to the next item and not waiting for the OK callback. If this is the case, I would recommend you use `async.eachSeries` from [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) library. This way, it won't proceed to the next item until you say you are done with the current item in your array.

Comment: Thanks, I am now using async/eachSeries, but as above, I am unable to figure out how to include the port's ondata callback into the loop !

Comment: I believe cb(); should be called inside the callback of post.write `port.write(outStr, function(err,res) { cb(); });` Remember to do error checking here of course.

Comment: Thanks, but no, it really needs to be called after the data is received back abd is validated so it needs to index to the next line only after the data is received and validated by ondata.

Comment: I have tried including the onData listener and then removing the listener, but that seems to make no difference:      port.removeListener('dataCallback',function(){});